# How to take metadata from .mp3 file and put it to a video as a text using FFmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, stream, broadcast

***In my previously opened topic:***

[How to make FFmpeg automatically inject mp3 audio tracks in the single cycled muted video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147086/how-to-make-ffmpeg-automatically-inject-mp3-audio-tracks-in-the-single-cycled-mu/65149530?noredirect=1#comment115196822_65149530)

I've got detailed explanation from @llogan how to broadcast looped short muted video on youtube automatically injecting audio tracks in it without interrupting a translation.

I plan to enhance the flow and the next question I faced with is how to dynamically put an additional text to the broadcast.

**Prerequisites:**

1. youtube broadcast is up and running by ffmpeg
2. short 3 min video is paying in infinity loop
3. audio tracks from playlist are automatically taken by "ffmpeg concat" and injected in the video one by one

this is a basic command to start translation:

> ffmpeg -re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -re -f concat
> -i input.txt -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy -g 20 -b:v 2000k -maxrate 2000k -bufsize
> 8000k -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my-key

**Improvements I want to bring**

1. I plan to store some metadata in audio files (basically it's an artist name and a song name)
2. At the moment a particular song starts playing artist/song name should be taken from metadata and displayed on the video as text during the whole song is playing.
3. When the current song finishes and a new one starts playing the previous artist/song text should be replaced with the new one etc

**My question is how to properly take metadata and add it to the existing broadcast config using ffmpeg?**

Comment: It is possible using the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter with `reload` and `textfile` options (see [Can you insert text from a file in real time with ffmpeg streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63586443/)). The problem is that the audio files listed in `input.txt` are basically treated as a single input and lose their "individuality". So the question becomes a matter of timing: how will you know when to update the title?

Comment: So if there is no way to use metadata of audio file as an input for text it becomes a really complex task. What I could assume is if we had files in `input.txt` called like **file1.m4a, file2.m4a** so we'd need to have separate text files corresponding to filenames like  **file1.txt, file2.txt** containing text and take text out of them. Then probably each time new song starts we should determine its filename duration or keep a separate file(-s) containing info about all tracks duration. But it doesn't seem a simple solution

Comment: basically this youtube channel is what I want to achieve [lil-peep radio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgSZ46yRPss)  And I realize they can use absolutely different approach like stream using OBS, Streamlabs overlays, some audioplayer as an audio input. But I look towards ffmpeg as a more lightweight and less hardware consuming solution

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly broad question and I don't have a complete solution. But I can provide a partial answer containing several commands that you can use to help implement a solution.

## Update text on video on demand

See [Can you insert text from a file in real time with ffmpeg streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63586443/)

## Get title & artist metadata

With `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=title -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp3
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=artist -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp3
```

Or combined: `format_tags=title,artist` (note that `title` will display first, then `artist`, regardless of order in the command).

## Get duration of a song

See [How to get video duration in seconds?](https://superuser.com/a/945604)

## What you need to figure out

The hard part is knowing when to update the file referenced in `textfile` in drawtext filter as shown in **Update text on video on demand** above.

## Lazy solution

Pre-make a video per song including the title and artist info. Simple Bash example:

```
audio=input.mp3; ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -i "$audio" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1280:720,setsar=1,fps=25,drawtext=text='$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=title,artist -of default=nw=1:nk=1 $audio)':fontsize=18:fontcolor=white:x=10:y=h-th-10,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 2 -ar 44100 -g 50 -b:v 2000k -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 6000k -shortest "${audio%.*}.mp4"
```

Now that you already did the encoding, and everything is conformed to the same attributes for proper concatenation, you can probably just [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) your playlist to YouTube (but I didn't test):

```
ffmpeg -re -f concat -i input.txt -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/my-key
```

Refer to your previous question on how to [dynamically update the playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65149530/).

References:

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Streaming to YouTube](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites)
- [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into specific size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305)
- [How to concatenate videos in ffmpeg with different attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367243/)